# if (window.location.hash !== "#search")

Tags: javascript

Is there anything wrong with this syntax? This doesn't seem to work for me, even though if I alert the hash-tag and it matches with my if statement.

my code:

```
if(window.location.hash) { 
   var thehash = window.location.hash;
   if (thehash !== "#search"){

      alert(thehash); // returns "#search"

      thehash = thehash.replace(/#/g, '/');
      window.location.replace("http://url.com/" + thehash + "/");
   }
}
```

Why does this still redirect urls containing #search

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Your code does not result in a redirection when URL fragment is `#search`. Tested in Chrome v23.

Comment: Futhermore, `thehash` is not defined. Maybe this is due to the copied excerpt.

Comment: @DavidMüller thanks, fixing it now, sorry

Comment: Thanks everyone, I used @keune 's advice and simply returned false if true , first, before the else if it is false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `return false` after `alert`, so it won't run the rest of your function

Comment: Thanks, keune..I've updated my code and it still doesn't work. Am I doing what you said incorrectly? thanks